# In Nougat Capture Image from Camera and get file from Uri

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

In Android Nougat and above versions the method to capture image from camera intent is changed and following code is working fine for me.

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                   // File file = new File(AppGlobal.URI_CAPTURED_IMAGE.getPath());

                                    AppGlobal.URI_CAPTURED_IMAGE = FileProvider.getUriForFile(parent, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", AppGlobal.getOutputMediaFile());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    AppGlobal.URI_CAPTURED_IMAGE = Uri.fromFile(AppGlobal.getOutputMediaFile());
                                }
                                camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, AppGlobal.URI_CAPTURED_IMAGE);
                                camera.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                                startActivityForResult(camera, WritePostFragment.REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO_CAPTURE);
```

In onActivityResult method I'm able to show the captured image in ImageViews as well.

```
Glide.with(parent).load(AppGlobal.URI_CAPTURED_IMAGE).centerCrop().into(profilePic_iv);
```

But when i use the same uri to get File then it says no file exists at given path. What could be the issue? How can i parse the Uri to get File. It seems to be version related stuff.

Sample uri is as follows:

> content://com.example.demo.provider/external_files/Camera/IMG_20171213_015646.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i parse the Uri to get File

You don't. Moreover, you do not need to. Your file is whatever `AppGlobal.getOutputMediaFile()` returns. You need to hold onto that value (including putting it in the saved instance state `Bundle`, in case your process is terminated while the camera app is in the foreground). See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.8/Camera/FileProvider) for how to use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` with `FileProvider`.

Comment: Actually I'm passing the uri as a string to my service which is responsible to upload the file to server. In that service i need to get File from that Uri path, because i can't pass file as extras

Comment: @UsmanRana: First, you can pass a `File` as an extra, as `File` is `Serializable`. Second, given a `File`, you can get the path as a `String` via `getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: Now, i got you. The original Uri of file is the one that AppGlobal.getOutputMediaFile() file gives me. The Uri given by FileProvider for Nougats is just to keep the original path unexposed. So, other apps can't access it.

Comment: @UsmanRana: "The original Uri of file is the one that AppGlobal.getOutputMediaFile() file gives me" -- that returns a `File`, not a `Uri`, based on your use of that method. But, yes, that is what I am referring to. The `FileProvider` `Uri` is for use by other apps, through `ContentResolver`. You do not need that -- the `File` will suffice. But, you need to hold onto that value.